# Class does not recognize attribute?

Tags: python, python-2.x

This is driving me crazy. I want the program to print the name "Frank". However, I get an error that says "AttributeError: 'People' object has no attribute 'called'". I've searched online and as far as I can tell I'm doing everything right, but since I'm getting an error obviously I'm not.

I'm using Python 2.

```
class People(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def called(self):
        return self.name

frank = People("Frank")

print frank.called()
```

What am I doing wrong?[image: Added screenshot for proof]

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: [Works on my machine.](http://ideone.com/nvVvrb)

Comment: In Python indentation is part of syntax - probably your `called` method is defined outside of class, as a standalone function (or maybe as local function to `__init__` method. Please, double check your indentation.

Comment: Added picture to show I really get the error, this is all the code I have in the program...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like an indentation problem.

[image]

Dots are spaces, arrows are tabs.

Even though tabs may *look* like they're equivalent to four spaces in your text editor, Python may not interpret them as such. As a result, you should never mix tabs and spaces. Use only one or the other. Preferably spaces.

---

I see you're using Notepad++. For ease of debugging, you can configure it to display tabs as arrows by going to View -> Show Symbol, and checking "Show White Space and TAB". You can also configure it to insert four spaces instead of a tab character when you press the tab key, via Settings -> Preferences -> Language Menu/Tab Settings -> Replace by space.

Comment: YES! This was exactly the problem. I had mixed spaces and tabs. Changed them all to tabs - problem solved. (I'll google why spaces are preferred).

Comment: @The6thSense Thank you, I intend to. SO is making me wait a few minutes before I'm allowed to do that.

Comment: @MarijkeVonk Short answer to why spaces are preferred: different editors will show tabs as different widths, but a space is always a space. It's about consistency and not being surprised by whitespace.

Comment: @MarijkeVonk sorry forgot the time period :).

Comment: this is so classic :)

Comment: @SethMMorton That explains it perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: An explanation on [why spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9456035/945456) and the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) that recommends using spaces.

Comment: Not sure about Notepad++ but many editors (Eclipse, vim I know for sure offhand) are smart enough to indent for you (such as hitting `Enter` after an `if something:` to the correct indentation level, and hitting backspace once will backspace an entire indentation level, even though everything really is spaces. Makes typing things easier than having to hit backspace 4 times, but no whitespace surprises